# "Tried to add property 'Id' when already added."-Error when implementing own class twice

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I would like to have a mapped class named "Message". This class should include an unique id, the title, the text, and information about the sender and the receiver. I need their User-ID an their name, so I've created another class named "User". This class include these two properties (later I'll create some methods for this class and use it in different classes, so I can not use onyl the class "Message").

This is my code

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User sender;
    public User receiver;
    public virtual string subject { get; set; }
    public virtual string text { get; set; }
}

public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message>, IMappedEntity
{
    public MessageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "MessageId");
        Map(x => x.sender.Id, "SenderId");
        Map(x => x.receiver.Id, "ReceiverId");
        Map(x => x.subject);
        Map(x => x.text);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to save only the User-ID of the sender and receiver, not their names. Because x.Id, x.sender.Id and x.receiver.Id have the property "Id", I wrote down a spezific name for them in the database.
But if I try to load the site, this error appears: *Tried to add property 'Id' when already added.*, even if their is no more property named "Id" after I definited the Name for the columns...

Could you give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an other solution: I changed the mapping of my Message-Map to this:

```
public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message>, IMappedEntity
{
    public MessageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Component(
            x => x.sender,
            userId =>
            {
                userId.Map(x => x.Id, "senderId");
            }
        );
        Component(
            x => x.receiver,
            userId =>
            {
                userId.Map(x => x.Id, "receiverId");
            }
        );

        Map(x => x.subject);
        Map(x => x.text);

    }
```

Now, I do not have to map the User-Class, so I don't have a table only with my Userids.

I'm not too familar with using nHibernate, so I'm not shure wether this is the best way to solve the problem, but in my eyes this fits a bit more to my problem then the solution presented by Chev (but I'm very grateful that you have answered me!)

Answer (score 2):

Change the MessageMap as follows.

```
public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message>, IMappedEntity
{
    public MessageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Sender);
        References(x => x.Receiver);
        Map(x => x.subject);
        Map(x => x.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is already very good, but I still have one problem: If I use your solution, I have to map the class "User", too. And because the two tables will be connected, I have to write all my Userids in the table "User" if I want to use them in the "Message"-table  Of cause, I could do this automatically when the user creates his account, but I don't think that's the best way.  Is there any possible solution without creating an additional table "User" in my DB?

Comment: You will have to map it so that NHibernate knows about it. I am not sure why you would not want to map it? If you don't want to use NHibernate to keep track of your entities, then look at a tool like Dapper http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: I want to map only the property "Id". The username can easily be changed by the user, so I don't want to save them. When I display the message to the user, I will search the username matching to the userid. But this will be done automaticly (the get-argument of my "name" property will do this). With your solution, I will end up having an extra table with all my userids. That's not very usefull, so I thought it might be a good idea to save the ids as if they are normal Guid-properties of the "Message" class (even if they are defined in the User-table)

Comment: Hi Chris. These are basic concepts of good design and dont see any benefit, only complications, with your proposed design - esp if "This class include these two properties (later I'll create some methods for this class and use it in different classes, so I can not use onyl the class "Message")" - Look to dapper if you want to bypass entities and simply map queries to classes.